# Explanation of Deprecation Warnings

Tags: templating

Why is this depreciated? Is there an example of the preferred method?

> Looping through element queries directly has been deprecated. Use the all() function to fetch the query results before looping over them.

Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

It means you've got a loop on an element query somewhere in your templates.  For example:

```
{% for entry in craft.entries.section('mySection') %}
    {{ entry.title }}
{% endfor %}
```

You should update it to use `.all()` like so:

```
{% for entry in craft.entries.section('mySection').all() %}
    {{ entry.title }}
{% endfor %}
```