# Looping through element queries directly has been deprecated

Tags: entries, pagination, deprecation

on the template

**_events.twig**

```
{% include "./components/_listing" with {
  entries: craft.entries.section('events').orderBy('eventStartDate ASC').limit(3),
  columns: 3,
  heading: 'On this month',
  art: 'art3',
  headings: true
} %}
```

**_listing.twig**

```
{% if pagination is defined and pagination == true %}
        {% paginate entries as pageInfo, pageEntries %}
    {% else %}
        {% set pageEntries = entries %}
    {% endif %}

    <div class="container">
        <div class="c-listing-items">
             {% for entry in pageEntries %}
    ~~~~
```

"Looping through element queries directly has been deprecated. Use the all() function to fetch the query results before looping over them."

The line number is `{% for entry in pageEntries %}`

I referred [Explanation of Deprecation Warnings](https://craftcms.stackexchange.com/questions/30960/explanation-of-deprecation-warnings) and [Output deprecation error](https://craftcms.stackexchange.com/questions/29366/output-deprecation-error)

But seems I'm away from those two answers.

Can someone suggest me to find a solution for this?

**Update:**

```
{% set featuredEvents = craft.entries.section('events').featuredEntry(1).limit(10).orderBy('offerStartDate') %}
```

**on the template**

```
{% for featuredEvent in featuredEvents %}
```

When we limit to 10, why `{% for featuredEvent in featuredEvents %} line highlight for

```
Looping through element queries directly has been deprecated. Use the all() function to fetch the query results before looping over them.
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For your first issue, if you are not paginating then your `{% else %}` should be:

```
{% set pageEntries = entries.all() %}
```

So that the query gets executed. In full:

```
{% if pagination is defined and pagination == true %}
        {% paginate entries as pageInfo, pageEntries %}
    {% else %}
        {% set pageEntries = entries.all() %}
    {% endif %}
```

Regarding the update to your question, it's the same thing.

Until you add `.all()` to your `featuredEvents` query (or any query), it's like the query hasn't run yet. Adding `.all()` executes the query.

Craft is smart enough to still run it without `.all()` but it will warn you hence the deprecation warning.

You should [read more about element queries](https://docs.craftcms.com/v3/dev/element-queries/) and [how to execute them](https://docs.craftcms.com/v3/dev/element-queries/#executing-element-queries).

Comment: Thank you, I amended the question with a similar issue, could you please check that too.

Comment: Yes, thank you, just coming back by reading the doc.